# How can Cloudflare determine the owner of a website?

Tags: dns-domain, domain

Assume that we have two websites with two different owners. Both of them set their domain name server to `john.ns.cloudflare.com` and `joly.ns.cloudflare.com`. The first owner set both domains in his account in CloudFlare and set server IP to his server IP, How can CloudFlare determine that this person is not the owner of the second domain?

Isn't this kind of a threat of our domain being hijacked by someone else?

Comment: Can you give us some more detail? what do you mean by "set their domain name server to" and "set both domains in his account"?

Comment: @GrahamHill when someone wants CloudFlare manage his website dns instead of install bind service, he can his domain nameserver to cloudflare nameservers that usually are `joly...` and `john...`.now if two person both set this nameservers for their domains,and second person before first person go in cloudflare and set first person domain for his self how cloudflare can detect this? I hope this be better explain :)

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question from cloudflare help center and I got this answer

> When a user is signing up to Cloudflare they are provided with 2 of
>   our DNS servers to switch their nameservers to from whatever their
>   current value is. We have more nameservers than john and joly. The act
>   of changing the nameservers to those specified for the user account
>   signing up a domain to the values during the setup process
>   demonstrates control of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

The name servers you're given are responsible for translating your the host name into an IP address, but clients won't know to query CloudFlare for the IP address. When making a DNS request, your domain name provider will tell you who's authoritative of the domain, meaning that which servers to query. Without setting CloudFlares servers in your domain name provider, they'll continue to point to whoever is authoritative, usually themselves if you're putting in records through their site. Once you add those name servers however, your domain name provider will start replying to queries saying they should see with CloudFlare to find the correct address.

When signing up for CloudFlare, you need to give them your domain before you set it up. At that point CloudFlare will check to see if someone else already added it to their system. If they did, CloudFlare won't give you a nameserver to set, and instead tell you that it's already in use. At that point you can contact support and work with them to sort it out.

Comment: " If they did, CloudFlare won't give you a nameserver to set, and instead tell you that it's already in use." This is not true,I have tested It and cloudflare don't tell you it has already set

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi Weird, I got that message trying to sign up a domain for CloudFlare when it turns out my friend signed it up for me. If that's the case, then this is a matter you should contact CloudFlare about.